# Angular Status 0 if Api offline

Tags: angular, api, http, ionic-framework, connection

I am trying to show a message if the API is offline on my angular app.

At my HttpInterceptor, I have:

```
return next.handle(request).pipe(
    tap(
        event => {
            if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                // console.log('all looks good');
                // http response status code
                //console.log(event.status);
            }
        },
        error => {
            if (error.status == 0) {
                error.message = 'API is Offline.', 'error'
            }
            console.error(error.status);
            console.error(error.message);
        }
    )
);
```

So i want to intercept the error to return the message for my Component or Service, when he fails.

My component calling a service:

```
this._service.new()
    .subscribe(
        res => {
        },
        err => {
          this._messageHelperService.showToast(err.error.message, 'error');
        }
    );
```

Can someone helps me ? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Throwing the error using `throwError` in the HttpInterceptor.

Example:

```
    tap(
        event => {
            if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                // console.log('all looks good');
                // http response status code
                //console.log(event.status);
            }
        },
        error => {
            if (error.status === 0) {
                return throwError('API is Offline., error')
               // error.message = 'API is Offline.', 'error'
            }
            console.error(error.status);
            console.error(error.message);
        }
    )
);
```

And then you can access the error in your component in the same way you are using.